# pdf tranformation with piecewise Y

Tags: probability

Having random variable X with pdf:

- $6x(1-x), \ x∈ [0,1]$
- $0, \ otherwise  $

I'm trying to calculate the pdf $f_Y(y)$, with Y random variable with pdf:

- $\sqrt{x}, \ x \geq 0 $
- $- \pi, \ x < 0$

From what I understand I can integrate $f_X(x)$ to obtain $F_X(x)$, then knowing that:
$$
for \ 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ \ F_Y(Y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(\sqrt{x} \leq y) =P(x \leq y^2) = F_X(y^2)
$$
I can calculate $f_y(y)$ for $\ 0 \leq x \leq 1$. I can do the same with $x \geq 1$ and obtain $f_y(y) = 0, \ for \ x \geq 1$. I'm having some problems dealing with the constant value $-\pi$:
as usual I write:
$$
for \ 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ \ F_Y(Y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(-\pi \leq y)
$$
now at this point I have no idea how to write $P(-\pi \leq y) = ? =F_x(g(y))$.
How can I handle the constant value there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\leq X\leq 1$ with probability one, it follows that $Y=\sqrt{X}$ with probability one and we conclude that the density for $Y$ is zero outside of the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: So since outside $[0,1]$ the probability is $0$, this means that every transformation applied there would have no effect?

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\Pr(Y = -\pi) = \Pr(X < 0) = 0.$$